# Forbid printing on generated PDFs (via prawn + combine_pdf)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I need to take a template (a pdf file) and add elements in it. I used prawn gem to generate a pdf with the elements and combine_pdf gem to combine this prawn pdf and the template. It works fine!

Now I need to add permissions to disable printing options. Prawn has an option for that but if I add it, I can't use combine_pdf to combine my template and this prawn pdf. Prawn can't start with an existing pdf (template system has been removed a long time ago...).

So I'm pretty stuck here, I looked everywhere in the web for a solution but couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 0):

instead of combine_pdf gem you can use [pdf-toolkit](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-toolkit/). it supports templating, combine pdf and set permissions. [the manual can be found from here](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-output-enc-perms).